# Contains con array de string

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una lista de objetos que tienen un campo de descripción. Como quiero hacer una búsqueda de manera dinámica con un formulario y demás me gustaría poder buscar objetos que tuvieran cualquiera de las formas que estén dentro de un array de string. Por ejemplo, si mi array tiene:

```
string[] palabrasQueBuscar = {"hola", "ho", "pepe"};
```

Me gustaría que la búsqueda de ese campo me diera los objetos que, en su campo descripción, tuvieran cualquiera de las formas de "hola", "ho" o "pepe".

He probado con esto en otras ocasiones:

```
string palabra = "hola";
grammars.Where("GrammarImprint.Description.Contains(@0)", palabra);
```

Pero esto solo me devuelve los referentes a una sola palabra. Si en vez de tener una string como tal lo cambio a un array de string me salta la siguiente excepción:

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException
{"No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'String'}
```

Por lo que imagino que no está definido el contains para una lista de objetos.

¿Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo? Necesito hacerlo usando específicamente dynamic LinQ.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

este es un problema comun en varios examenes de programacion.

Con LinQ lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

Convertir tu frase en un array y luego buscar que palabra contiene las que estas buscando

```
string[] palabrasQueBuscar = { "test" ,"como" };

var frase = "Hola como estas".Split(' ');
```

2 Maneras de hacerlo en LinQ (Contains y Any)

```
var contiene2 = palabrasQueBuscar.Where(x => frase.Contains(x)).ToList().Count();

var contiene = frase.Where(a => palabrasQueBuscar.Any(b => a == b)).ToList().Count();
```

Si quieres que te regrese la palabra que encontro solamente quitale el Count

Te recomiendo que uses un ToUpperCase o ToLower para que no haya problema en las busquedas

Comment: En efecto, eso funciona perfectamente utilizando linq a secas. El problema que tengo es que tengo que usar, sí o sí, **dynamic linq** para crear la query completa que me gustaría hacer. Tengo todo funcionando bien menos esta parte.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la consulta sería de esta manera:

```
    string[] palabrasQueBuscar = {"hola", "ho", "pepe"};
    grammars.Where("@0.Contains(Description)", palabrasQueBuscar);
```

Comment: Eso lo que hace es que busca la propiedad Description dentro de cada uno de los componentes que hay en el array. Es justo lo contrario de lo que estoy buscando. Pensé que a lo mejor se podía hacer con All o Any, pero no hay documentación sobre cómo usar esos métodos en Dynamic LinQ con predicados...

Answer (score 0):

La forma de solucionar ese inconveniente es:

```
string palabra = "hola";
grammars.AsQueryable().Where("GrammarImprint.Description.Contains(@0)", palabra);
```

para mas información puede visitar este [Ejemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CXfG4d)

Comment: Si bien podría ser una solución, sería oportuno que describas qué operación concreta hace el código que pusiste y qué pasos empleaste para llegar a la solución, te recomiendo que leas [cómo escribir una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)